# If $\lim a_n=a$, then $\lim\frac{a_1+2a_2+\cdots +na_n}{n^2}=\frac{a}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a real sequence such that $\lim a_n=a$. Let $b_n=\frac{a_1+2a_2+\cdots +na_n}{n^2}$. Show that $\lim b_n=\frac{a}{2}$.

Let $s_n=a_1+\cdots +a_n$. Then it is well known that $\lim \frac{s_n}{n}=a$. We have $b_n=\frac{(n+1)s_n}{n^2}-\frac{s_1+\cdots+s_n}{n^2}$. Clearly $\lim \frac{(n+1)s_n}{n^2}=\lim \frac{n+1}{n}\lim \frac{s_n}{n}=a$. But I cannot show that $\lim \frac{s_1+\cdots+s_n}{n^2}=\frac{a}{2}$. Need some help to complete this. Thanks.

Comment: I would appreciate if someone help me to complete it in my approach.